# How to optimize code for multiple return value?

Tags: c

Here an example of my code:

```c
void MyFunc()
{
    if(funcA(varA) == 0)
    {
        if(funcB(varB) == 0)
        {
            if(funcC(varC) == 0)
            {
                //Success funcC
            }
            else
            {
                //error with funcC
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //error with funcB
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error with funcA
    }
}
```

So the code will be like, if `funcA()` returns zero ONLY then execute funcB(), if `funcB()` returns zero ONLY then execute `funcC()` and so on. My question is how can I replace that nested `if...else` statements with some other optimized method?

Comment: And how your compiler did not already optimized it?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Dont try to write optimized code, write code that is optimizable.

Comment: Also, when you talk about optimization: did you figure out the bottleneck first?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think he's is trying to optimize readability, not performance

Comment: @MikevanDyke so in that case, this q is opinion-based. What is readable to me, can be complex to others.

Comment: __I'm voting to close this as Opinion-based: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. Also, code-refactoring is more suitable in [codereview.se]__

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, it's somehow opinion-based, but he also provides his expectations on how the nested `if...else...`-statements should be replaced, so I think, it's ok?

Comment: @MikevanDyke as I mentioned , I still think this is a better fit for code review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent a bunch of scopes and if's nested you can fail-fast instead:

```
if(funcA(varA)) // if funcA returns 0, only then proceed
  return;

if(funcB(varB))
  return;

if(funcC(varC))
  return;
```

You can expand the `if`s if you want to print some error :

```
if(funcA(varA))
{
  //error..
  return;
}
```

Or if you don't need such information, use a short-circuiting one-liner, this will only run `funcB` if `funcA` returns `0` etc:

```
!funcA(varA) && !funcB(varB) && !funcC(varC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is exactly equivalent to

```
void MyFunc()
{
    if(funcA(varA)){
        //error with funcA
        return;
    }
    if(funcB(varB)){
        //error with funcB
        return;
    }
    if(funcC(varC)){
        //error with funcC
        return;
    }
    //Success funcC [sic.]
}
```

which also scales better in the sense that there's an obvious pattern should you need a `funcD`.

Comment: You're a `funcD`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Are you a Buff Orpington chicken? My daughter has identified that as her favourite breed.

Comment: Oh but of course I am. Did she mention any miscellanea? A sombrero perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

Unless your coding standards mandates it, the original code is clear enough and provides places for commenting if needed.

In C language, low level optimization should be left for the compiler. The responsability of the programmer is to produce readable code with the correct high level algorithms.

The number of lines matters in optimization in old basic or in javascript, not in C.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
void MyFunc()
{
    if(funcA(varA) == 0 && funcB(varB) == 0 && funcC(varC) == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

if your first function evaluates to desire results only then funcB is called and same in case of next functions.
The only disadvantage is you can't check which of them doesn't produce desire result.

Comment: In case if some error occurred, how will you identify which function is failed out of `funcA()`, `funcB()` and `funcC()`?